# Deleting duplicated words in a very large words list

Tags: python, duplicates, word-list

I'm a beginner at this and I wrote a program that generates a wordlist following specific algorithms. The problem is it makes duplications.

So I'm looking for a way to make the code iterates through the range given or the number of words given to make without duplicating words.

OR write another program that goes through the words list the first program made and delete any duplicated words in that file which is going to take time but is worth it.

The words that should be generated should be like this one `X4K7GB9y`, 8 characters in length, following the rule
`[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z]`, and the code is this:

```py
import random
import string

random.seed(0)
NUM_WORDS = 100000000

with open("wordlist.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as ofile:     
    for _ in range(NUM_WORDS): 
        uppc = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, k=4)
        lowc = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, k=1) 
        digi = random.sample(string.digits, k=3) 
        word = uppc[0] + digi[0] + uppc[1] + digi[1] + uppc[2] + uppc[3] + digi[2] + lowc[0] 
        print(word, file=ofile)
```

I'll appreciate it if you can modify the code to not make duplications or write another code that checks the wordlist for duplications and deletes them. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What exactly do you need to achieve? do you need to generate random values (8 digits) or check if a file contains duplicate words?

Comment: Store the created word in a `set()`. Before writing to file check if word in set() - if so - don't write. You need to be able to hold all words in memory for this.

Comment: @GowthamJayachandiran any of the both would be helpful, either make the code not duplicate words or write another code that checks file for duplicated words and deletes them

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm not that good at python at all I'll appreciate if someone tell me where to put that set() exactly !! this is why I asked for help

Comment: @Sasquatch  **I'm a beginner at this and I wrote a program**  ... how did you end up this program if you are unable to understand what it does, where it does it and where to add a set to do it what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent duplicate words from the get go by remembering what you created and not write it again.

This needs a bit of memory to hold 100.000.000 8 letter words - you can lessen that by only remembering the hashes of words. You will miss out on some hash collisions, but with about `26**5 * 10**3 = 11,881,376,000` possible combinations you should be fine.

```
import random
import string

random.seed(0)
NUM_WORDS = 100 # reduced for testing purposes
found = 0
words = set()
with open("wordlist.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as ofile:     
    while found < NUM_WORDS: 
        # get 5 upper case letters, use the 5h as .lower()
        l = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, k=5) 
        d = random.sample(string.digits, k=3) 
        word = l[0] + d[0] + l[1] + d[1] + l[2] + l[3] + d[2] + l[4].lower()
        if hash(word) in words:
            continue
        print(word, file=ofile)
        words.add(hash(word))
        found += 1
```

Comment: it gives this error : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Study\CODING\Python\fuckyouworld", line 13, in <module>
    word = l[0] + d[0] + l[1] + d[1] + l[2:4] + d[2] + l[4].lower()
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Answer (score 1):

Given that your algorithm creates a list of words(unique or not).
You could use set to retain only the unique words, look at the example below.

```
word_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word1"]
unique_words = set(word_list)
```

It returns the unique_words list that includes only ["word1", "word2", "word3"].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using a `set()` to deduplicate the words list:

```py
import random
import string

random.seed(0)
words_count = 100_000_000
words = set()

while len(words) < words_count:
    u = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, k=4)
    l = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, k=1)
    d = random.sample(string.digits, k=3)
    words.add(f'{u[0]}{d[0]}{u[1]}{d[1]}{u[2]}{u[3]}{d[2]}{l[0]}')

with open('wordlist.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    print(*words, file=f, sep='\n')
```

Bear in mind that it will take lots of memory and a long time to generate a hundred million random words.

Answer (score 0):

Below program will generate unique values following the condition and also writes the same into a text file.

this set of code creates unique values

```
import random
import string 

 n = 100
 l = []
    
for i in range(n):
    word = chr(random.randint(65, 90)) + str(random.randint(1, 9)) + chr(random.randint(65, 90)) + str(random.randint(1, 9)) + chr(random.randint(65, 90))+ chr(random.randint(65, 90)) + str(random.randint(1, 9)) + chr(random.randint(65, 90)).lower()
    l.append(word)
finallist = list(set(l))
```

And the below codes will write the outcome into a file.

```
with open("Uniquewords.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in finallist:
        f.write(i)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```